# How to make sure a http request was not handcrafted?

Tags: mobile, ssl, cryptography

How can I make sure the data I'm sending on a http request to a server was actually generated by my application (mobile application) and not handcrafted by the user?

For example: If I have a game and I want to submit the user's score to the server, how to make sure the user doesn't see the request data and start sending handcrafted scores to the server?

I thought about using a hash algorithm together with an app secret key. So the request would send four pieces of data: the score, the date, the userid and a hashed (score+date+userid+secret_key). Then, I could perform this hash operation again on the server and verify the data is legitimate. However, how can I protect myself from the case where the hacker is able do disassemble the application and see what the secret_key is?
Is there a better way to do this other than signing the request with a hash code?

Comment: The only proper idea is to move some business logic of your game to the server for verification, or involve the server in some other way to ensure that there's control on the server side over the gaming process and the results are not fake.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, you can't.  Anything the user can do through the application, they can do by reverse-engineering the application and doing what it would do.  All you can do is make things harder for them.